# How to find the difference between two times

Tags: python, datetime

I'm trying to figure out a way to take two times from the same day and figure out the difference between them. So far shown in the code below I have converted both of the given times into Int Vars and split the strings to retrieve the information. This works well but when the clock in values minute is higher than the clock out value it proceeds to give a negative value in minute slot of the output.

My current code is:

```
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()
clocked_in = now.strftime("%H:%M")
clocked_out = '18:10'

def calc_total_hours(clockedin, clockedout):
    
    in_hh, in_mm = map(int, clockedin.split(':'))
    out_hh, out_mm = map(int, clockedout.split(':'))
    hours = out_hh - in_hh
    mins = out_mm - in_mm
    return f"{hours}:{mins}"



print(calc_total_hours(clocked_in, clocked_out))
```

if the clocked in value is `12:30` and the clocked out value is `18:10`

the output is:

```
6:-20
```

the output needs to be converted back into a stand time format when everything is done `H:M:S`

Thanks for you assistance and sorry for the lack of quality code. Im still learning! :D

Comment: Look into [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) as this does all the magic for you...

Comment: Convert everything to minutes, seconds, milliseconds, whatever, then subtract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, in order to fix your code, you need to convert both time to minutes, compute the difference and then convert it back to hours and minutes:

```py
clocked_in = '12:30'
clocked_out = '18:10'

def calc_total_hours(clockedin, clockedout):
    in_hh, in_mm = map(int, clockedin.split(':'))
    out_hh, out_mm = map(int, clockedout.split(':'))
    diff = (in_hh * 60 + in_mm) - (out_hh * 60 + out_mm)
    hours, mins = divmod(abs(diff) ,60)
    return f"{hours}:{mins}"

print(calc_total_hours(clocked_in, clocked_out))
# 5: 40
```

Better way to implement the time difference:

```
import time
import datetime

t1 = datetime.datetime.now()
time.sleep(5)
t2 = datetime.datetime.now()

diff = t2 - t1
print(str(diff))
```

Output:

```py
#h:mm:ss
 0:00:05.013823
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the most reliable way is to represent the times a `datetime` objects, and then take one from the other which will give you a `timedelta`.

```
from datetime import datetime

clock_in = datetime.now()
clock_out = clock_in.replace(hour=18, minute=10)

seconds_diff = abs((clock_out - clock_in).total_seconds())

hours, minutes = seconds_diff // 3600, (seconds_diff // 60) % 60

print(f"{hours}:{minutes}")
```